# { [Error: private_key and client_email are required.] code: 'MISSING_CREDENTIALS' }

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload file to google cloud storage with node js, but I keep receiving error:

> '{ [Error: private_key and client_email are required.] code:
>   'MISSING_CREDENTIALS' } '

```
 var gcloud = require ('gcloud') ({
        projectId: 'my project',
        keyFilename: '/keyFile.json
}) 

var gcs = gcloud.storage ();

    var backups = gcs.bucket ('backups'); backups.upload ('a.pdf', function (err, file) {
        if (err)
            return err;

    });
```

Comment: path to key file is correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are providing a JSON file for an OAuth client rather than a service account private key. Go to the [Service Accounts page in Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/projectselector/permissions/serviceaccounts) and create a new JSON key for either a new or existing service account.